# Deep list of 5 or more levels, showing all subsections and also when \ref {} is referenced

Tags: cross-referencing

It's my first query and I'm learning to use Latex.
Hello!! I would like to see how I can do to reference with `\ref{A.i.2.b.ii}` (five levels), and also reference `\ref{B.ii.3.b.ii.}` in the pdf completely in another section. I want the subsections to be differentiated to know where the area that I want to see is located. Still, I only get the ending for the first reference `2.` as well as for the second reference `1.ii.` and I would like to be able to display the entire section completely; that is `A.i.2.b.ii` as too `B.ii.3.b.ii.` in the pdf.

I tried to use some codes but the difficulty was that it had no depth problem.

When I tried it with some parameters (without using MyEnumerate and with less than 5 levels), it worked for me with some code I found. Still, I need 5 levels (or maybe more), and that's where the difficulty starts, when I add more levels I try to reference with `\ref{A.ii.2.b.ii}` to see the path specific to the `A.ii.2.b.ii` levels, but the `2` element appears, the same happens with the other references. Code I implemented below after searching many examples.

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}


\section{Adding item}

\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{6}
\setlistdepth{6}
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{6}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label={\Alph*.},ref={\Alph*.}}
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label={\theenumi.\roman*.},ref={\theenumi.\alph*.}}
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label={\theenumi\theenumii.\arabic*.},ref={\theenumi\theenumii.\arabic*.}}
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label={\theenumi\theenumii\theenumiii.\alph*.},ref={\theenumi\theenumii\theenumiii.\alph*.}}
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label={\theenumi\theenumii\theenumiii.\theenumiv\roman*.},ref={\theenumi\theenumii\theenumiii.\theenumiv\roman*.}}

\begin{myEnumerate}%[Alph.]
\item \label{A.} 
    \begin{myEnumerate}%[A.roman.]
        \item \label{A.i.} I want this to appear as the subsection.5 A.i. for full reference.
            \begin{myEnumerate}% [A.i.arabic.]
               \item \label{A.i.1.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.1. for full reference.
               \item \label{A.i.2.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2. for full reference.
               \begin{myEnumerate}%[A.i.2.alph.]
                   \item \label{A.i.2.a.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.a. for full reference.
                   \item \label{A.i.2.b.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.b. for full reference.
                   \begin{enumerate}%[A.i.2.b.roman.]
                       \item \label{A.i.2.b.i.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.b.i. for full reference.
                       \item \label{A.i.2.b.ii.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.b.ii. for full reference.
                        \item \label {A.i.2.b.iii.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.b.iii for full reference.
                   \end{enumerate}%[A.i.2.b.roman.]
               \end{myEnumerate}%[A.i.2.alph.]
            \end{myEnumerate}%[A.i.arabic.]
        \item \label{A.ii.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.ii. for full reference.
            \begin{enumerate}%[A.ii.arabic.]
                \item \label{A.ii.1.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.ii.1. for full reference.
            \end{enumerate}%[A.ii.arabic.]   
    \end{myEnumerate}%[A.roman]
\item \label{B.}
    \begin{myEnumerate}%[B.roman.]
        \item \label{B.i} I want this to appear as the subsection B.i. for full reference.
       \item \label{B.ii.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii. for full reference.
       \begin{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.arabic.]
           \item \label{B.ii.1.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.1. for full reference.
           \item \label{B.ii.2.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.2. for full reference.
           \item \label{B.ii.3.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3. for full reference.
           \begin{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.3.alph.]
               \item \label{B.ii.3.a.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.a. for full reference.
               \item \label{B.ii.3.b.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.b. for full reference.
               \begin{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.3.b.roman]
                   \item \label{B.ii.3.b.i.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.b.i. for full reference.
                   \item \label{B.ii.3.b.ii.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.b.ii for full reference.
                   \item \label{B.ii.3.b.iii.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.b.iii for full reference.
               \end{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.3.b.roman]
           \end{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.3.alph.]
           \item \label{B.ii.4.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.4. for full reference.
           \item \label{B.ii.5.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.5. for full reference.
       \end{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.arabic.]
       \item \label{B.iii} I want this to appear as the subsection B.iii. for full reference.
    \end{myEnumerate}%[B.roman]
    \item \label{D} the same for the others.. THANK YOU!!!
\end{myEnumerate}%[Alph]
\section{Reference to item}
I want to reference this $\backslash$item $A.i.2.b.ii.$ completely, but it comes out like this \ref{A.i.2.b.ii.}.

I want to reference this $\backslash$item $B.i.3.b.ii.$ completely, but it comes out like this \ref{B.ii.3.b.ii.}.

I want to reference this $\backslash$item $B.ii.3$ completely, but it comes out like this \ref{B.ii.3.}.

I want to reference this $\backslash$item $A.i.2.$ completely, but it comes out like this \ref{A.i.2.}.

I want to reference this $\backslash$item $B.ii.$ completely, but it comes out like this \ref{B.ii.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other variations I tried were, but they worked.

```
%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Alph{enumi}} 
%\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}}
%\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\arabic{enumiii}}
%\renewcommand{\theenumiv}{\alph{enumiv}}
%\renewcommand{\theenumv}{\roman{enumv}}

%\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.\theenumiii.}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\theenumi.\theenumii.\theenumiii.\theenumiv.}




%\setlist*[myEnumerate,1]{label={\Alph*.},ref={\theenumi\Alph*.}}
%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Alph{enumi}}
%\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label={\theenumi.\roman*.},ref={theenumi\roman*.}}
%\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label={\theenumi\theenumii.\arabic*.},ref=%{\bfseries\theenumii\arabic*.}}
%\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label={\series\Alph*.\series\roman*.\series\arabic*.\series\alph*.}}
%\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label={\series\roman*.}}





%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Alph{enumi}} 
%\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}}
%\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\arabic{enumiii}}
%\renewcommand{\theenumiv}{\alph{enumiv}}
%\renewcommand{\theenumv}{\roman{enumv}}
```

Thank you very much in advance and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Very good, I have solved my problem thanks to your help. For people who will be using this code, please note that I have not changed an `enumerate` in the subsection to `myEnumerate`, if that is changed, the code works great for many layers!
```
\begin{enumerate}%[A.ii.arabic.] \item \label{A.ii.1.} I want this to appear as subsection A.ii.1. for complete reference.
\end{enumerate}%[A.ii.arabic.] ```
And if in another section they don't use names for the subsections, they can change it with the following code:
```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
````

Answer (score 6):

In order to define a numbering scheme that is hierarchical, both in the label and reference, just use the `label*` key provided by [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem); from the [`enumitem` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem): "`label*` is like `label` but its value is appended to the parent label."

And since you don't have a distinction between the label and its `\ref`erence, you don't need to supply a `ref` value.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{6}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label={\Alph*.}}
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label*={\roman*.}}
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label*={\arabic*.}}
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label*={\alph*.}}
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label*={\roman*.}}

\begin{document}

\section{Adding item}

\begin{myEnumerate}%[Alph.]
  \item \label{A.}
  \begin{myEnumerate}%[A.roman.]
    \item \label{A.i.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i. for full reference.
    \begin{myEnumerate}% [A.i.arabic.]
      \item \label{A.i.1.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.1. for full reference.
      \item \label{A.i.2.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2. for full reference.
      \begin{myEnumerate}%[A.i.2.alph.]
        \item \label{A.i.2.a.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.a. for full reference.
        \item \label{A.i.2.b.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.b. for full reference.
        \begin{myEnumerate}%[A.i.2.b.roman.]
          \item \label{A.i.2.b.i.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.b.i. for full reference.
          \item \label{A.i.2.b.ii.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.b.ii. for full reference.
          \item \label {A.i.2.b.iii.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.i.2.b.iii for full reference.
        \end{myEnumerate}%[A.i.2.b.roman.]
      \end{myEnumerate}%[A.i.2.alph.]
    \end{myEnumerate}%[A.i.arabic.]
    \item \label{A.ii.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.ii. for full reference.
    \begin{enumerate}%[A.ii.arabic.]
      \item \label{A.ii.1.} I want this to appear as the subsection A.ii.1. for full reference.
    \end{enumerate}%[A.ii.arabic.]   
  \end{myEnumerate}%[A.roman]
  \item \label{B.}
  \begin{myEnumerate}%[B.roman.]
    \item \label{B.i} I want this to appear as the subsection B.i. for full reference.
    \item \label{B.ii.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii. for full reference.
    \begin{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.arabic.]
      \item \label{B.ii.1.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.1. for full reference.
      \item \label{B.ii.2.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.2. for full reference.
      \item \label{B.ii.3.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3. for full reference.
      \begin{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.3.alph.]
        \item \label{B.ii.3.a.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.a. for full reference.
        \item \label{B.ii.3.b.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.b. for full reference.
        \begin{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.3.b.roman]
          \item \label{B.ii.3.b.i.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.b.i. for full reference.
          \item \label{B.ii.3.b.ii.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.b.ii for full reference.
          \item \label{B.ii.3.b.iii.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.3.b.iii for full reference.
        \end{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.3.b.roman]
      \end{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.3.alph.]
      \item \label{B.ii.4.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.4. for full reference.
      \item \label{B.ii.5.} I want this to appear as the subsection B.ii.5. for full reference.
    \end{myEnumerate}%[B.ii.arabic.]
    \item \label{B.iii} I want this to appear as the subsection B.iii. for full reference.
  \end{myEnumerate}%[B.roman]
  \item \label{D} the same for the others.. THANK YOU!!!
\end{myEnumerate}%[Alph]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for deciphering what the OP wants